# What did I break, VS Code now complains about Readme markdown generated by Azure Devops

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-devops

Not sure what I did, but I mist have broke something.  I was using the MSSQL extension to query sql and the next thing I know Im getting complaints about a readme file I added when I setup the repo for my project. dotnet build still succeeds, but I dont recall seeing these messages when I first started the project, nor the red squiggles in the file itself.

```
Version: 1.39.1 (system setup)
Electron: 4.2.10
Chrome: 69.0.3497.128
Node.js: 10.11.0
V8: 6.9.427.31-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.17134
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Look at the status bar at the bottom right and select the correct language mode, which should state "Markdown" right to the bell.

Comment: Yes, see new screenshot above

Comment: I just closed and re-opened VS Code and its gone away